# Mongoose date schema returns wrong format for date on front end (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, database-schema, mean-stack

I am writing a web app using MongoDB, Mongoose.js, Express.js, npm, and AngularJS.

I have a form with a date range input field, the data gets sent to the server, and back to Angular by using:

```
    <td> Date Range: </td>
    <td> {{post.FromDate}} - {{post.ToDate}} </td>
```

My Mongoose schema looks like this:

```
     var mongoose = require('mongoose');

     var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        FromDate: Date,
        ToDate: Date,
     });
```

However, this shows the date in the following format for users to see:

2015-07-09T07:00:00.000Z - 2015-07-16T07:00:00.000Z

Is there a cleaner format? How do I get something like: YYYY/MM/DD - YYYY/MM/DD?

Comment: Either change how you store the date in ur mongodb, or on the way out, use the javascript date functions to parse into a format suitable for your UI
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the angular date filter in your view

{{post.FromDate | date: yyyy/MM/dd}} - {{post.ToDate | date: yyyy/MM/dd}}